# Autocomplete feature for textbox in Jenkins plugin development

Tags: jenkins, plugins, autocomplete, jelly

Does anyone have any ideas or know any documentation to help me adding the autocompletion feature to the textbox in Jelly while developing Jenkins plugin?
I know that it uses YUI autocomplete feature from Yahoo but I could not find an solid example for Jenkins.
Thanks in advance...

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

As strange as it is, I am not able to find any docs on the subject at the moment.

Jenkins support AJAX based auto-completion with automated control population. The form element must belong to a Describable and its Descriptor needs to have a public method with expected signature. It will be called whenever form needs to perform the auto-completion and it will serve the returned values to the user. The method name must be a `doAutoCompleteFooBar` for `fooBar` entry field. See example:

- UI: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ui-samples-plugin/blob/2ab631671f90abf496e319b8334ce32c414d9dc7/src/main/resources/jenkins/plugins/ui_samples/AutoCompleteTextBox/index.jelly#L29-L31
- Backend: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ui-samples-plugin/blob/2ab631671f90abf496e319b8334ce32c414d9dc7/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/ui_samples/AutoCompleteTextBox.java#L45-L59